# ffmpeg Upscale Multiple Images Zoom-Pan

Tags: video, ffmpeg, images

I was successfully able to to use upscale on one image before pan and zoom using this code:

```
ffmpeg -y -t 15 -i 1.jpg -t 15 -i 2.jpg -t 15 -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=8000:-1,zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0020,1.5)':d=417[v0]; [1:v]zoompan=z='if(lte(zoom,1.0),1.5,max(1.021,zoom-0.0020))':d=417,fade=t=in:st=0:d=5[v1];[v0][v1]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0,format=yuv420p[v]" -c:v libx264 -map "[v]" -s "800x450" -t 300 -threads 2 video.mp4
```

But i am not able to the same on multiple images using:

```
ffmpeg -y -t 15 -i 1.jpg -t 15 -i 2.jpg -t 15 -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=8000:-1,zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0020,1.5)':d=417[v0]; [1:v]scale=8000:-1,zoompan=z='if(lte(zoom,1.0),1.5,max(1.021,zoom-0.0020))':d=417,fade=t=in:st=0:d=5[v1];[v0][v1]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0,format=yuv420p[v]" -c:v libx264 -map "[v]" -s "800x450" -t 300 -threads 2 video.mp4
```

This is the error generated:

Input link in1:v0 parameters (size 1280x720, SAR 59001:59000) do not match the corresponding output link in0:v0 parameters (1280x720, SAR 1:1)
[Parsed_concat_5 @ 0000022fb3004b80] Failed to configure output pad on Parsed_concat_5
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #1:0
Conversion failed!

Any help would be appreciated thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

`ffmpeg -y -i 1.jpg -i 2.jpg -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=8000:-1,zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0020,1.5)':d=417:s=800x450,setsar=1[v0]; [1:v]scale=8000:-1,zoompan=z='if(lte(zoom,1.0),1.5,max(1.021,zoom-0.0020))':d=417:s=800x450,setsar=1,fade=t=in:st=0:d=5[v1];[v0][v1]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0,format=yuv420p[v]" -c:v libx264 -map "[v]" -t 300 -threads 2 video.mp4`

zoompan operates on each image individually. By adding `-t 15` before each image, it will operate upon 375 frames of each image, producing, for each, a zoompan of 417 frames! I don't think this is what you want.

Since concat is complaining about mismatching aspect ratios, setsar is added to force a common SAR.

Comment: How to do this from an arbitrary number of input images from a text file?